# vector<unique_ptr> gives troubles

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have short code as below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() {}
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> m; 
    // Change the above line to "unique_ptr<int> m;" removes the compilation error
    // Or add a line "A(A const&) = delete;" removes the compilation error also
};

struct B
{
    tuple<A> t;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

VC2013 NOV CTP compiler gives errors:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function xmemory0   593
```

Is this a compiler bug or code bug?

Comment: [works here with g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4427e08c08e83a19)

Comment: Thus it is a compiler bug. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you deleting the copy constructor? Couldn't you just make it `private` if you don't want it to be used? And this error is because something you're doing is triggering the copy constructor. I'm not well verse enough in C++ to tell you what that is though.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to use the default copy constructor with a unique_ptr: after all, it should be unique...  So it this sense, it looks like a code bug.

Comment: It compiles in VS2013 Update 1.

Comment: @Gonmator VS2013 Update 1 and Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CT, which one is the latest?

Comment: @user1899020 I guess the Update 1 is the latest of both.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Visual Studio; according to @Gonmator's comment it's been fixed as of VS2013 Update 1.

It might have been similar to reported bugs such as 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801826/std-tuple-with-rvalue-references-not-working-if-clr-enabled 
or
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/891428/c-std-pair-has-no-default-move-constructor 
— apparently MSVC has had several residual bugs involving "move semantics + std::tuple".